# Is there an equivalent for :HEX and :OCT in current Pascal?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I am trying to transpose an old Pascal programm into one that compiles (and work) with Free Pascal.
One mechanism that I have encountered is a sort of conversion done at the reading of the value:

```
readln (file,ValueHex:HEX);
```

or

```
readln (file,ValueOct:OCT);
```

In the later case, when the value read in the file was "12" (value in octal), the value stored in "MyValue" was "10" (value in decimal).

For writting these values the code was:

```
writeln (hex(ValueHex,4), oct(ValueOct,3));
```

and now is:

```
writeln (HEXSTR(ValueHex,4), OCTSTR(ValueOct,4));
```

The writting part works as intended but in all the Free Pascal documentation I could not find the equivalent of **:HEX** and **:OCT**, does it even exist or do I have to write dedicated functions converting hexadecimal and octal values to decimal ones?

Comment: At least in Delphi, `StrToInt` can be used to convert a hexadecimal string into an integer. `StrToInt('$20')` yields `32`.

Comment: This also works in Free Pascal, as long as the string you want to convert is correctly prefixed (with $ or &). This is not the case in my input file (no prefix) the knowledge of the base is in the programm not in the file itself. I would have preferred a solution that does not impact my input file format, but I keep it in mind if nothing else arise, thanks !

Comment: Valram: Of course, you can do `StrToInt('$' + mystring)` if `mystring` isn't prefixed with `$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You will need to read as string and do the conversion yourself. I haven't even heard of these extension before, so it is probably not a common one. Which dialect is it?

Note that FreePascal also supports & as octal and % as binary prefix.

```
uses sysutils;
begin
  Writeln (StrToInt('$1234'));
  Writeln (StrToInt('&1000'));
  Writeln (StrToInt('%1010101'));
end.
```

For hex there is also an option without prefix:
https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/strutils/hex2dec.html